# how do i keep php from trying to interpret now() within a php statement

Tags: php, mysql

I keep killing my page with the error "Call to undefined function now()" from within the query that I have shortened from what it actually is below

```
$RToDB = mysql_query("INSERT INTO LIP(id,updated,detected) 
        VALUES(
        '".$_COOKIE["ID"]."',
        now(),
        now()
        )");
```

Anyway is there something I am not seeing that I am doing wrong? How do I submit now() as part of the query without php trying to interperet it?

edit: The error actually came from defining a variable with now(); my bad

Comment: don't use `mysql_query()`. The `mysql_xx()` functions are being deprecated and are not recommended for use. The PHP manual recommends switching to either the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: It looks ok. Show us more code and the actual error.

Comment: Also, be aware that cookies can be manipulated by the user. Therefore, your code is open to SQL injection attack unless you sanitise the variable properly. (switching to `mysqli_xx()` or PDO will allow you to use parameterised queries, which solves this problem)

Comment: I verified (using a sha family hash+ a bunch of salt+ a security phrase) the cookie before any of the page was processed.

Comment: Details on parameterised queries?

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` is uppercase

```
INSERT INTO LIP(id,updated,detected) 
    VALUES(
    '".(int)$_COOKIE["ID"]."',
    NOW(),
    NOW()
```

remember that `$_COOKIE` is client based so they can change it, try not to rely on that, at least make it an `(int)` to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: OP should really look at parameter binding, which will avoid a ton of these errors. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: MySQL doesn't care about the case, so not sure that `NOW()` will make any difference, but fully agree with you about the cookie.

Comment: The error actually came from defining a variable with now(); my bad

Comment: Additionally, I verified (using a sha family hash+ a bunch of salt+ a security phrase) the cookie before any of the page was processed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use double quotes " in php unless necessary. It's slower.

Use ' as much as you can instead.

Strings surrounded by " are parsed for replacing variables like in "Hello $username" the variable $username will be detected and replaced by its value.